# How to convert QString to typename using templates?

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I would like to write a generic template method that computes some things and in the end returns a value of `typename T`. The value comes from a QString so I need to convert the QString to the specified `typename T`. Unfortunately I only find the `toDouble()`, `toInt()`,... methods.

What I need is:

```
QString s = 3.1415;
double d = s.toType<double>();
float f = s.toType<float>();
int i = s.toType<int>();
```

I don't want to call the `toDouble()`, `toInt()`,... because I cannot select them at compile time.

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** I could write my own specialized template functions that do exactly this. So

```
double myOwnConvertFunction<double>(const QString& s)
```

would then simply call the s.toDouble()

I thought that Qt might already have a built-in way?

Comment: QVariant(s).value<T>() could work here.

Comment: That sound good, but does this have performance implications? The QString is converted to a QVariant before, right?

Comment: Afaik the qvariant class can store string's dptr directly inplace and share with it, incuring no further heap allocation cost. You can check the source code to be absolutely certain.

Comment: Ok, thanks for now! I will report back :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert the `QString` to `QVariant` and then use `value<T>()`

```
QVariant(s).value<T>()
```

`QVariant` shares the data with `QString`, so no deep copy happens here and the result should be pretty fast as well. For extra comfort, Qt has

```
qvariant_cast<T>(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html). You can do it using the `QTextStream`'s [`QString` constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#QTextStream-3). Your code will probably look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T toType(const QString& string) {
    T result;
    QTextStream stream(&string, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    stream >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Incidentally, depending on whether you are suffering from the [pre-gcc 5.0 `stringstream` move-constructor bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) you can also accomplish the `QTextStream` construction inline like so:

```
template <typename T>
T toType(const QString& string) {
    T result;

    QTextStream(&string, QIODevice::ReadOnly) >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan. This looks good from a style perspective but I'm afraid that there is a performance problem with it. I will investigate Johannes Schaub's suggestion (see comments of my question).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a non-member `toType`:

```
template <typename T> struct type { };

template <typename T>
auto toType(QString const& q)
    -> decltype(toType(q, type<T>{}))
{
    return toType(q, type<T>{});
}
```

with a bunch of overloads as appropriate:

```
double toType(QString const& q, type<double> ) {
    return q.toDouble();
}

int toType(QString const& q, type<int> ) {
    return q.toInt();
}

float toType(QString const& q, type<float> ) {
    return q.toFloat();
}

...
```